# Minified file does not use minified module

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I have a node.js folder which contains a main js file and several other js files which contain the functions that the main js file will import.

I have minified all the js files in this folder.

In the original main.js file, it calls another module with the following line;

```
var func= require('./func');
```

After minification, this line remains the same. However, func.js is changed to func.min.js after minification. Do I have to modify the minified file manually to have it import func.min.js this way?

```
var func= require('./func.min');
```

It is quite tedious to manually make changes to the minified file. What is the most efficient way to minify my js files and get the main.min.js working?

I am using Webstorm file watchers to minify the js files.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a bundler (such as Browserify or WebPack) to minify & combine everything together.

Comment: you should have a dev boolean variable to toggle the change.

Comment: SLaks, Browserify seems to be for web browsers and for front-end code. My node.js code is for backend. Is browserify applicable for me?

Comment: Why would you minify node.js code? There is zero advantages

Answer (score 0):

To get your main.js working, change the require line in main.js to;

```
var func= require('./func.min');
```

This will work because you are using Webstorm file watchers to minify the js files. Therefore, when func.js is changed, func.min.js will be automatically generated.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for at first but the solution is even better. Marked as answer.